# Decay of Fourier Coefficients and Smoothness

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if $|\widehat{f}(k)| = |a_k| < \frac{M}{|k|^{2 + \varepsilon}}$ then $f$ is continuously differentiable. I'm not quite sure how to do this. There was another question on the site ([Rate of decay of Fourier coefficients vs smoothness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30066/rate-of-decay-of-fourier-coefficients-vs-smoothness)) but it makes an incorrect assumption: that we can termwise differentiate the Fourier series. Here is what I've done so far.

It's obvious that $\sum a_k e^{ikx}$ converges uniformly to some function $g$ and that $g \equiv f$ almost everywhere, with $g$ continuous. So we need to show that $g$ is continuously differentiable. The continuity part is easy once we have differentiability, so we just need to show differentiability. To that end we have

$\lim_{y \to x} \frac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y} = \lim_{y \to x} \frac{\sum a_k e^{ikx} - \sum a_k e^{iky}}{x-y} = \lim_{y \to x} \sum a_k \left( \frac{e^{ikx} - e^{iky}}{x-y} \right) = \sum a_k \lim_{y \to x} \left( \frac{e^{ikx} - e^{iky}}{x-y} \right) = \sum a_k ike^{ikx}$

which converges based on our bound on $a_k$. However, I don't really know how to prove the third equality. I don't think that the inner functions are monotone in absolute value, and I can't think of any dominating function. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See if the answer to a question I posed along similar lines helps.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318804/relation-between-function-discontinuities-and-fourier-transform-at-infinity

Comment: Um... isn't your third inequality exactly the same problem you had with the other problem? You are actually termwise differentiating the series, just in more cumbersome notation.

Comment: You're right, I realized later that it would imply that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the theorem

> If $g_n \to g$ pointwise, and $g_n$ differentiable, and that $g'_n \to h$ uniformly, then $g$ is differentiable with derivative $h$.

Let $g_n$ in this case be the Fourier partial sums $\sum_{|k| \leq n} a_k e^{ikx}$.

Comment: I was looking for some theorem like this but whenever I searched "uniform convergence derivative" the hits were always "not differentiable". Thanks so much! And what a useful theorem.

Comment: In case you are looking for a source of this statement, it is in Chapter 7 of Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_. In the edition in my office it is Theorem 7.17.